# microsoft sql server management studio Incorrect syntax near '|'

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT IPD.Task_grp "Task Group", TASK.STARTW "Starting Area", TASK.ENDW "Destination Area", IPD.Nxt_Work_Grp,IPD.Nxt_Work_Area 
"Drop Area", IPD.Prty "Priority", IPD.Stat_Code "Status"
FROM int_path_defn IPD, 
(SELECT start_curr_work_grp || start_curr_work_area StartW,
        start_dest_work_grp ||start_dest_work_area EndW 
FROM task_hdr WHERE task_id='332800') TASK WHERE IPD.CURR_WORK_GRP || IPD.Curr_Work_Area=TASK.StartW
AND IPD.Dest_Work_Grp || IPD.Dest_Work_Area=TASK.ENDW
```

I am getting

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '|'.`
```

Please help what could be the wrong. same query executed successfully in oracle sql developer

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server uses `+` for string concatenation instead of `||`.

Comment: I think it's not simply a string concatenation, but a function Oracle specific.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax is wrong. "||" - even "|" - has no sense in TSQL.

Which means either the person writing this SQL has no clue OR - more likely - it is coming from another server type. Bad news: SQL is not really standardized, everyone has his own extensions.

Time to do your job and fixing the syntax. And yes, this can be tendious work.